# How can I translate this curl command so that it works in a PHP script?

Tags: php, curl

CLI CURL -> PHP CURL (get only header)

```
curl \
 --head \
 --request GET \
 --silent \
 --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXX' \
 http://example.com/remote/foler/file.zip
```

I need to only get response header without download the entire file every time.

I also need to use GET method because remote server restrict me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are only few steps need to be taken. 
1.Initialize
2. Set the options
3. Execute
4. Close the connection

```
<?php

$url = "www.example.com";

//initilise
$ch = curl_init();

//set the option
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

//no body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);

//set the method 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');    

// request header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);

//execute
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$information = curl_getinfo($ch);

//close the connection
curl_close($ch);


echo '-- REQUEST HEADER --------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
print_r($information['request_header']);
echo '--------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo '-- RESPONSE HEADER -------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
print_r($result);
echo '--------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
```

Curl uses GET by default. If you wanna set it to POST method then the option is CURLOPT_POST.
You can set many options, have a look at php.net manual.

Comment: Thank you but I need to get only response headers and not the body.
The remote zip file is ~200MB and I do not want to download every time.

Your code return header+body.

Comment: Okay, just edited, if you don't wanna return the body then you need to set CURLOPT_NOBODY option to true. I hope that helps.

Comment: As you can see from the request header, if you set CURLOPT_NOBODY to true, the method used is HEAD and not GET. I need to use GET.

Comment: Don't worry, anytime!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see this is not a real question, is more a task to do. The response for this is in the PHP manual http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php. Check specially the `CURLOPT_HEADER`.

If you have a php version equal or superior to 5.5 you could check http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html as an abstract layer over cURL.

And as always, search inside Stackoverflow to see if the question or similar already exists: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=curl+headers . That will help to maintain the quality of Questions, and also, answers.

Comment: I tried the CURLOPT_HEADER but it change the request method to HEAD. As I wrote, I need them to use the GET method, but do not want to download the file.